# Accessibility of Google Sign-In button with a web app

Tags: html, accessibility, google-signin

I'm integrating [Google Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) with my web app and it automatically renders a button based on an ID I provide the `gapi.signin2.render()` function. My concern is that all of the documentation uses a `<div>` as the button's containing element, so a user is forced to click the button using a mouse instead of having the option to tab to the element and activate it that way. Even after the `render()` call, the container contains only a mix of `<div>`, `<span>`, and `<svg>` elements, so there's nothing a user could tab to.

Google provides documentation on [building a custom sign-in button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button), but even that uses markup that looks like so:

```
<div id="gSignInWrapper">
  <span class="label">Sign in with:</span>
  <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn">
    <span class="icon"></span>
    <span class="buttonText">Google</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I try to use a `<button>` or `<a>` as the container, I cannot use the enter key while focused on the element to invoke the event handler on the button.

How can I make a Google Sign-in button that's accessible for users who don't use a mouse?

Comment: That's horrible!  Google usually tries to build accessibility into their stuff.  While there might be a way to work around it, it needs to be addressed with google so that everyone doesn't code their own workaround.  Please take this to them and have them fix it.  Shame on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [attempting to find help](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/webmasters/UZhZthKIGeQ) on the official Google product forums, I solved this by following the documentation on [building a custom button](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button), but changing the markup from what is shown there and instead using an anchor tag. So in the end, it looked something like:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="google-signin">
    ... More markup here ...
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
auth2.attachClickHandler(
  document.getElementById('google-signin'),
  { 'scope': 'profile email' },
  onSignIn,
  onFailure
);
```

The element is now focusable and behaves correctly upon pressing the Enter key.